# long table problems with horizontal line

Tags: longtable, line, horizontal

Hi all I want to produce long table so I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text- not needed for a longtable

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.5pt}
\begin{longtable}{|
>{\columncolor{lightgray}}p{0.2\linewidth} | p{0.175\linewidth} |}
\hline
foo & bar \\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}
\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable} 

Table \ref{tab:myfirstlongtable} shows my first longtable.
\end{document}
```

The code works fine but there is a small problem: when the table is separated to multiple pages there is no horizontal line drawn in between, here is the output at which I highlighted the problem:

[image]

I want a horizontal line to be drawn at the end of the table at page 1 and at the beginning of the table at page 2

How to achieve that ?

Your help is appreciated

Comment: You do not want a line in the coloured column?

Comment: You might mention that the code comes from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616272/colored-long-tables  honestly I would not mix colured panels and rules, the rules are not really helping

Comment: Well the problem is not related to whether the table is colored or not, I tried the code without colors and the same problem exists. The problem here with cline and I don't know how to solve it

Comment: I want a complete horizontal line to be drawn at the end of the table at page 1 and at the beginning of the table at page 2. This is not working with cline

Answer (score 1):

This code, respecting the `longtable` syntax  (caption & label in the `firsthead` section) and using `\hhline` does what you want, I think:

```
\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.5pt}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\columncolor{lightgray}}p{0.2\linewidth} | p{0.175\linewidth} |}
\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable} \\
\endfirsthead
\caption{Your caption here (continued)}\\
\hline
\endhead
\hline
foo & bar \\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline%\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \hhline{|--|}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar \\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}
\end{longtable}
```

[image]
[image]